# Inaccurate rendering of shapes in Mapbox

Tags: openstreetmap, geojson, mapbox, mbtiles

I am trying to create an overlay of the streets of the US. The map streets v8 provided by Mapbox is missing some information that I need. So, I downloaded the OSM files ([from here](https://download.geofabrik.de/)) and filtered out everything but roads. Now, I am trying to upload this data as a layer in Mapbox but the shapes are inaccurate. I tried different ways, like uploading GeoJSON files or Mbtiles files. Every time I get different shapes.

For example, this image shows 3 lines all representing the same road. The red one is created in Mapbox studio as a line shape. Black one is from an uploaded Mbtiles file and Blue is from an uploaded GeoJSON file of Alabama. The road starts from ["lat": 34.8174377, "lon": -86.9436697] to [ "lat": 34.8175178, "lon": -86.9439487]. You can view the original this road [here](https://overpass.kumi.systems/api/interpreter?data=%5Bout:json%5D;way(475110135);(._;%3E;);out;).

[image]

Have anyone encountered a problem like this with Mapbox or any other map provider? Is there a short fix for this?

Comment: Mapbox requires styles(.json) to represent data. check out the style for layout like placement.